# update column values by other column values in postgresql

Tags: sql, sql-update, greenplum

what i have

```
id  s_1     s_2      s_3      s_4     s_5     s_6     s_7      s_8

 ax    1      0         0       0       0        0       0       0
 bx    0      1         0       0       0        0       0       0
 cx    0      0         1       0       0        0       0       0
 dx    0      0         0       1       0        0       0       0
 ex    0      0         0       0       1        0       0       0
 fx    0      0         0       0       0        1       0       0
 gx    0      0         0       0       0        0       1       0
 hx    0      0         0       0       0        0       0       1
```

I am trying to update my column values as below .

if i have 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, as column values from s1 to s8 then it should be updated as 1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0

if i have 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 as column values from s1 to s8 then it should be updated as 0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0

if i have 0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0 as column values from s1 to s8 then it should be updated as 0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0

if i have 0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0 as column values from s1 to s8 then it should be updated as 0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0

if i have 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0, as column values from s1 to s8 then it should be updated as 0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0

if i have 0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0 as column values from s1 to s8 then it should be updated as 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0

if i have 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0, as column values from s1 to s8 then it should be updated as 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0

if i have 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 as column values from s1 to s8 then it should be updated as 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1

Output looks like below

```
 id  s_1     s_2      s_3      s_4     s_5     s_6     s_7      s_8

 ax    1      0         1       0       1        0       1       0
 bx    0      1         1       0       1        0       1       0
 cx    0      0         1       0       1        0       1       0
 dx    0      0         0       1       1        0       1       0
 ex    0      0         0       0       1        0       1       0
 fx    0      0         0       0       1        1       1       0
 gx    0      0         0       0       0        0       1       0
 hx    0      0         0       0       0        0       0       1
```

Comment: Don't add the `postgresql` tag if you are using Greenplum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_name AS o
   SET (s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, s_5, s_6, s_7, s_8) = (n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5, n_6, n_7, n_8) 
  FROM (
       VALUES 
         (1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0),
         (0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0), 
         (0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0), 
         (0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0), 
         (0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0),
         (0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0),
         (0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0),
         (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
       ) as n (
         s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, s_5, s_6, s_7, s_8,
         n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5, n_6, n_7, n_8
       ) 
 WHERE (o.s_1, o.s_2, o.s_3, o.s_4, o.s_5, o.s_6, o.s_7, o.s_8) = (n.s_1, n.s_2, n.s_3, n.s_4, n.s_5, n.s_6, n.s_7, n.s_8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a single SQL update solution out there, but the following multi-statement is a lot easier to write (and to debug):

```
update my_table -- case 1: 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
  set s1 = 1, s2 = 0, s3 = 1, s4 = 0, s5 = 1, s6 = 0, s7 = 1, s8 = 0
  where s1 = 1 and s2 = 0 and s3 = 0 and s4 = 0 
    and s5 = 0 and s6 = 0 and s7 = 0 and s8 = 0;
```

Then, for case 2:

```
update my_table -- case 2: 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
  set s1 = 0, s2 = 1, s3 = 1, s4 = 0, s5 = 1, s6 = 0, s7 = 1, s8 = 0
  where s1 = 0 and s2 = 1 and s3 = 0 and s4 = 0 
    and s5 = 0 and s6 = 0 and s7 = 0 and s8 = 0;
```

You can write the rest of the cases (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8).

Comment: Yeah.I am trying for single SQL update solution instead of  writing multi Sql statements.

Comment: It's totally possible to do that. It reminds me of digital circuits when I needed to add two 8-bit integers, and use the least number of transistors to do it (optimal solution). If you really are into it, you'll need to develop the full list of truth tables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) for each one of the eight bit you have. If you spend a couple of hours, I would love to see your optimal solution.